# Android - Notify the user about availability of new version from a Service

Tags: android

I have written code to programmatically check a URL the for new version of application from a `Service`. The URL will return the latest version and URL of the APK file.

Now how can I notify the user about the update from the `Service`?

I want to show some dialog box/some message box in the layout itself with the direct link to the APK or a clickable link where user can manually download the APK file.

```
if (latestVersionCode > currentVersionCode) {
 // Notify the user
}
```

Comment: Why would you waste the phone's resources to do something that the Android Market already does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to notify users to an update of your app even when they are not using it? If I were you I would avoid that practice I know as a user if I started getting notifications of individual app updates while I wasn't even using that app It would likely get uninstalled immediately. If you are going to check from a service at arbitrary times (once a day or something) I think you should just store a boolean flag that indicates to the main activity of your app that an update is available, then whenever the app is launched and that flag is true you can show a dialog that prompts the user to install the new version. This way they are getting the message only when they actually use your app. But I suppose if you are deadset on letting them know you can use the NotificationManager from your service to put something into their notification bar.